# How to add auto document for method & class & field in C# with ReSharper 5?

Tags: resharper

Visual Tomato AssistX provides a menu to automatically add method/class documents for the C++ functions.

Does ReSharper provide similar functions that I can use to add document for method/class?

Comment: Good question that I couldn't find a solution for. Did you find a way to do this?

Answer (score 7):

I don't think Resharper does this for methods but if you want to insert file headers have a look at this [post](http://scottlaw.knot.org/blog/?p=453). If you want to add a method comment you can just place your cursor on an empty line above one of your method and insert 3 slashes which will insert a comment block for you to fill out.

```cs
public ActionResult Index(int page)
    {
        return View();
    }
```

with /// inserted:

```cs
/// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="page"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public ActionResult Index(int page)
    {
        return View();
    }
```

Comment: I　ｏｎｌｙ　ｇｅｔ　/// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>

Comment: if your method is public void DoSomething(){} this is all you get. What does your method signature look like?

Comment: Link is dead :(, do you have an updated link? I'm interested in doing this as well.

Answer (score 3):

I'm using [GhostDoc](http://submain.com/products/ghostdoc.aspx) for that.